# Incompatibility between Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2013

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, web-applications

I am given an old Visual Studio 2010 ASP.NET MVC project to fix some defects. Is there any way I can continue it in VS 2013? I opened the project in VS 2013 once but didn't change anything. But now when I try to open it from VS 2010 again, it says that my project is incompatible with the Visual Studio version. How can I recover it?

Comment: Open up the project file (csprok/vbproj) and change this line from 12.0 to 10.0. <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>. It might work...

Comment: @TheShaman There's no .csproj file in my folder. However there's a .publishproj file and it has the above line in it with 10.0 as the version.

Answer (score 1):

After whole two days I found a way to fix this. When the folder is opened as a website in VS 2010 and closed, incompatible or not, a .sln file (Microsoft Visual Studio Solution file) will be saved in a new folder in C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects. I added the line `TargetFrameworkMoniker = ".NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.0"` under the line `ProjectSection(WebsiteProperties) = preProject`. When I tried to open the website folder again, it loaded without any issue.